# $d(x,y)=\sqrt {|x_1−x_2|+|y_1−y_2|}$ is a metric on $X\times X$. Is the metric space $(X,d_2)$ complete?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $x = (x_1, x_2), y = (y_1, y_2)$ and $d(x,y)=\sqrt {|x_1−x_2|+|y_1−y_2|}$ be a metric on $X\times X$.
Is the metric space $(X,d)$ complete?

Comment: If $X_i=(x_i,y_i)$ is cauchy in $(X,d_2)$ then note that $\{x_i\},\ \{y_i\}$ are Cauchy wrt $|\ |$ So we have limits $x_\infty,\ y_\infty$ Note that $(x_\infty,y_\infty)$ is limit of $X_i$

Comment: Can you confirm that the metric is $d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{|x_1-x_2| + |y_1 - y_2|}$ and not $d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{|x_1-x_2|^2 + |y_1 - y_2|^2}$?

Comment: @Stefan4024 you are right. In fact, I would ask for usual $d_2$ metric. Sorry for this. But as I see, the method of solution is same :) Thank you very much for your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_i = (x_i,y_i)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then note that both of the sequences $\{x_i\}$, $\{y_i\}$ are Cauchy, as $|x_i - x_j| \le ||X_i - X_j||$. But we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete so both $\{x_i\}$, $\{y_i\}$ converge to let say $a,b$, respectively. Now because of this $\exists N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ n > N_1 \implies |x_{n} - a| < \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$ and $\exists N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $ n > N_2 \implies |y_{n} - b| < \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}$. Now choose $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then we have that: $$ n>N \implies ||X_n - (a,b))|| = \sqrt{|x_i - a| + |y_i - b|} < \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon^2}{2} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{2}} = \epsilon$$

Therefore $X_i$ converges to $(a,b)$ and hence $\mathbb{R}^2$ is complete.